AFC Champions League quota
2024-25 AFC Champions League Elite and AFC Champions League Two winners get an entry to the 2025-26 AFC Champions League Elite league stage and play-off, respectively. I am not sure, however, it deducts their corresponding national quota. There is no explicit explanation in the AFC official regulation documentation.
